# Communication between Android App client and Python server over internet

Tags: python, android

I have a python server running on a desktop and an android app client on phone/tab. Both are connected to internet (without static ip). What are the ways client and server can communicate? Is setting up webservice on server only option? These days internet service providers don't support direct socket communication between subscribers. Thanks.

Comment: As-is, this question is too vague to have a single correct answer.  There are a wide variety of ways for apps and servers to communicate, even including direct socket communication in certain circumstances.  It might be answerable with more information.

Comment: I understand :). So to provide more details, I have a Postgres server and Python based app running on a desktop which is connected to i/net through a modem (so it will always get private IP). I have an android client app running on mobile/tab, connected to i/net using a data SIM. The android app needs to send event updates to the Python server on regular basis (few KBs on each update). I am trying to figure out best way to accomplish this comm. - preferably using open-source/freeware. I don't want to setup webservices because it would be an overkill. Hope this clarifies. Thanks.

Comment: you could move your code to AWS and then use their api to send data.

Comment: You do not need extra software as you have already your server on your pc your said. The Android client will connect to the router of your pc using the internet ip of that router. Then the router forwards connection to your pc.

Comment: Thanks 1lb3r for your response. So you are suggesting me to move data from Postgres to AWS-DynamoDB and my architecture will be something like: (Python Server) <----> (AWS-DynamoDB) <----> (Android Client). Is that correct?

Comment: blackapps, I am not sure what you are recommending. There won't be anything on router to listen to android client. I guess it wont know which machine (of all that are connected to it) to forward that to :(